# Signal separation

Tags: linear-systems, source-separation, decomposition

This is probably a blind signal separation problem of sorts, but it seems like it should be easier than I am finding it.

Let’s say I have N time series, each of length [M x 1] that are a superposition of the same 2 signals, each with individual, random time delays relative to eachother. I want to determine what the two components, or “atoms” of the signal are, given a large number of examples with different delays. The problem could be represented:

A*x_n = b_n + e_n,

Where A = [A1, A2], a M x 2*M matrix and A1 and A2 are M x M Toeplitz matrices with columns representing shifted versions of the signal atoms, b_n is the [Mx1] nth time series, e_n is the random noise for the nth time series, and x_n is a [2M x 1] sparse vector that has exactly 1 non-zero entry in the first half (corresponding to a column of A1 representing a delay for atom 1) and 1 non-zero entry for the second half (corresponding to a column of A2 representing another delay for atom 2).

Not a hard problem to solve if you know A1 and A2. But what if you don’t know A1 or A2? How do you estimate the filter shapes (i.e. signal atoms) for each Toeplitz matrix? I have a myriad of signals (i.e. N is large), and would like to automate the estimation of A1 and A2. This problem has to have a standard name and presence in DSP literature but I do not know what even to call it. Any insight appreciated, thank you